# Delete row in a PrimeFaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 3.5 and I am implementing the [DataTable - ContextMenu](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableContextMenu.jsf) component.
However, I want to delete a row by clicking on one cell in the row.

My JSF page:

```
<h:form id="form">

    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

    <p:contextMenu for="productID" widgetVar="cMenu">
        <p:menuitem value="Edit Cell" icon="ui-icon-search"
                    onclick="productService.showCellEditor();return false;" />
        <p:menuitem value="Delete Row" icon="ui-icon-search"
                    onclick="productService.delete();return false;" />
    </p:contextMenu>

    <p:dataTable id="productID" var="product"
                 value="#{productService.getListOrderedByDate()}"
                 editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="productTable"
                 paginator="true" rows="10"
                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">

        <f:facet name="header"> Airbnb Product  </f:facet>

        <p:ajax event="cellEdit"
                listener="#{productService.onCellEdit}"
                update=":form:messages" />

        <p:column headerText="id" style="width:15%">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{product.id}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{product.id}" style="width:96%" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        ...
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

I have implemented a delete method in my service which should work. However, when I press the delete button in my context menu nothing happens. What could the cause of the problem be?

**UPDATE**

I did it like on the PF Page with:

```
public void delete() {
    log.info("Deleting data:");
    log.info(selectedRow.getId());
//  productDAO.delete(selectedRow);

}
```

and my datatable:

```
                <p:contextMenu for="productID" widgetVar="cMenu">
                    <p:menuitem value="Edit Cell" icon="ui-icon-search"
                        onclick="productService.showCellEditor();return false;" />
                    <p:menuitem value="Delete" update="productID" icon="ui-icon-close"
                        actionListener="#{productService.delete}" />
                </p:contextMenu>

                <p:dataTable id="productID" var="product"
                    value="#{productService.getListOrderedByDate()}"
                    editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="productTable"
                    paginator="true" rows="10"
                    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                    selection="#{productService.selectedRow}" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{product.id}">
```

However, when I want to get the ID from selected Row I get a `NullPointerException`. I really appreciate your answer!!

Comment: is it a java bean method `productService.delete();` you are trying to execute in your js `onclick` callback? If it is , you can't do it like this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way to delete a row using context menu...

```
<p:menuitem value="Delete" update="productID" icon="ui-icon-close" action="#{productService.delete}"/>
```

Add to your table :

```
<p:dataTable selection="#{productService.selectedRow}" selectionMode="single"....
```

In your bean

```
public void delete() {  
    carsSmall.remove(selectedRow);  
}  

//declare selectedRow variable + getter/setter
```

Took it from the primefaces showcase : [DataTable - ContextMenu](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableContextMenu.jsf)

Comment: thx for your hint. However, I implemented it like that, BUT I get a `NullPointerException`(pls see my Update)

Comment: where is the exception coming from ? also can you confirm that the `selectedRow` being updated each time you trying to delete a row ?

Comment: the exception is coming from `   log.info(selectedRow.getId());` because `selectedRow` is `Null`. The Table should be updated because of the `IDs`. However, I do not know why its `NULL`?

Comment: do you have `update="productID"` in your `<p:menuitem value="Delete"` ? try to figure out how to make the `selectedRow` to be selected with primefaces datatable first... that you should be able to delete... I haven't worked with `selection` in primefaces datatables... Maybe the `rowKey="#{product.id}"` is not unique ?

Comment: thx for your help. Now it works;)... after a server and project clean;-)