# remove row from datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I don't know how to remove a row from datatable.

This my Facelet:

```
<p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Valider" update=":messages"  oncomplete="dialogdelete.hide()"
    actionListener="#{agentBean.btnDelete}"   styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="icon-ok"/>
```

Session bean:

```
public void delete (Agentministere agentministere) {
    agentministereFacade.remove(agentministere);
}
```

Managed Bean:

```
public String btnDelete (){
    manager.delete(agentministere);
    return "AgentList";
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16146454/delete-row-in-a-primefaces-datatable this thread might be helpful. Also, could you post code for datatable?

Comment: What exactly is your concrete problem? That you forgot to update the table with the new list with the row removed, or to send a redirect after post?

Comment: when I press the delete button nothing happens. What could the cause of the problem be?

Comment: But you're instructing JSF to update only the `:messages`, not the table. I'm also not seeing anywhere that you're reloading the list from the DB in action method. Why do you think that *something* visually would happen?